# Regex Find Replace Dreamweaver

Tags: html, regex, cross-browser, dreamweaver

I am trying to get regular expressions that will do these cases:

**Case 1:**

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #RANDOM_COLOR, #RANDOM_COLOR);
```

with

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #RANDOM_COLOR, #RANDOM_COLOR); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #RANDOM_COLOR, #RANDOM_COLOR);
```

**Case 2**

```
box-shadow: RANDOM_TEXT;
```

with

```
-webkit-box-shadow: RANDOM_TEXT;
box-shadow: RANDOM_TEXT;
```

I just want to then take use of the Control+F feature in Dreamweaver and replace the text by using regular expressions.

[image: Dreamweaver Replace Feature]

Thank you

Comment: I am aware of services that do cross browser compatibility, but I am currently working with inline-styles for ease of design instead of pure CSS files which these services usually target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver is using the Javascript Regex flavor.

### Find 1:

```
([ \t]*)(background:\s*-webkit-linear-gradient\(top\s*,\s*(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})\s*,\s*(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})\s*\)\s*;)
// assuming these are hexadecimal colors like you indicated with #
```

### Replace 1:

```
$1background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, $3, $4); 
$1$2
```

### Find 2:

```
([ \t]*)(box-shadow:\s*([^;]+)\s*;)
```

### Replace 2:

```
$1-webkit-box-shadow: $3;
$1$2
```

---

### Explanation of 1st find pattern:

All space characters `\s` are optional (thanks to `*`). Also, literal parentheses were escaped. In the replacement, the `$1`, `$2` etc indicate *`[capturingGroup n]`*.

```
(                          # capturing group #1
    [ \t]*                 # 0 or more spaces and/or tabs (could be any number of both)
)
(                          # capturing group #2

    background:\s*-webkit-linear-gradient\(top\s*,\s*
    (                      # capturing group #3
        #[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}  # a number sign and a string with 3 or 6 digits that's made of a-zA-Z0-9 (aka. hexadecimal characters)
    )
    \s*,\s*
    (                      # capturing group #4
        #[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}
    )
    \s*\)\s*;
)
```

Comment: If they are hexadecimal, you only need [a-fA-F0-9]

Comment: @inhan: Can you please add some explanation on how this works? Just Case 1 will do. Thank you so much.

Comment: @bluejamesbond No problem. I added explanation for the first case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the reason for regex.

Why can't you do a find for:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB, #999);
```

and replace with this:

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BBB, #999);background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB, #999);
```

Same thing goes with the shadow...

Comment: Who is downvoting?  The original question has since been edited.  The answer was correct until the question changed.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just make "match case" and use "Replace all" / "replace" that looks like:

Case 1:

"Find"

```
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB, #999);
```

"Replace"

```
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BBB, #999);    
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB, #999);
```